# Convert any valid date format to date in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

How can we check if a string is a valid date without specifying the format in MySQL.A user may enter below formats;

```
21-08-2013
21/08/2013
2013/08/21
21jan2018
```

I don't know the format in advance which a user may enter.
I tried :

Select str_to_date() but here I need to specify format which I don't want.
I just want to check if a string is valid date without specifying the format.

Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: Why not control the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All four of the date strings you showed us in the question can be converted to a MySQL date using `STR_TO_DATE` with an appropriate format mask.  So, you should be able to simply check for these date patterns, if all you want is to know if you could convert them to dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    col REGEXP '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}' OR
    col REGEXP '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}' OR
    col REGEXP '[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}' OR
    col REGEXP '[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but the formats are not fixed,the user may choose to enter a valid date string in different format.

Comment: @RR MySQL doesn't have any function in house which just tell you if a string is valid date or not.  Other than listing out the accepted patterns yourself, your best bet would be to ensure that invalid data never makes it into your database.  Or, convert everything to UNIX timestamps before bringing it into MySQL.

Comment: If you can give me some context as to these dates, maybe I can give a more complete/concise answer.